# Is it a sin to ask Allah for signs?

Tags: practical-islam, allah

Is it sin to ask Allah for signs? Like for example, asking Allah to make something happen to give me a sign. Or asking Him to make “xyz” happen to let me know if what I’m doing is good or not.